# Especialización void en plantilla de no-tipo

Tags: c++, template

Tengo una clase con una variable-miembro `std::optional`; esta clase se usará a su vez como argumento de plantilla de otra, por lo que no puedo usar argumentos en su constructor:

```
#include <optional>

template< int SZ > struct Store {
    Store( ) { value = SZ; }

    std::optional< int > value;
};
```

Con eso, le puedo asignar un valor inicial al miembro `value`. Sin problema.

Ahora, necesito soportar también la no-inicialización del miembro `value`. Pero no encuentro la sintaxis a usar:

```
template< > struct Store< void > { std::optional< int > value; }
```

> error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list

```
template< void > struct Store { std::optional< int > value; }
```

> error: ‘void’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
> error: template parameter ‘int SZ’ redeclared here

- ¿ Hay alguna forma de hacer lo que pretendo especializando a partir de `Store`, o necesito crear una clase no-plantilla distinta para el caso de no-inicializar ?

#### Observación:

No puedo usar un valor literal como especialización, porque todos los valores de `int` pueden ser usados como inicialización de `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de `void` podrías usar el valor 0:

```
template< > struct Store< 0 > { std::optional< int > value; };
```

Dado que en la plantilla estás usando valores de tipo `int` en vez de tipos, no es posible usar `void`, ya que este tipo no es convertible a un valor numérico

Comment: No lo había indicado en la pregunta (la acabo de editar), pero, de todas formas, me das la respuesta: `no es posible usar void, ya que este tipo no es convertible a valor numérico`. *Ergo* no se puede hacer .... *ergo* necesitaré una `struct` nueva para el caso de no-inicializar.

Comment: El problema no es que `void` no sea convertible a valor numérico, el problema es mezclar dos familias de parámetros plantilla: en `template<int SZ>`  el parámetro `SZ` es un valor, mientras que en `template<void>` el parámetro es tipo. Un parámetro `void` jamás puede tomar el lugar de un parámetro valor porque `void` no es instanciable (*‘void’ is not a valid type for a template **non-type** parameter*).